# Linking a Vue file with Django template

Tags: django, vue.js

I have a Django project contains multiple templates like this:

```html
      <body>
         <div>
            <ul>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">
                  customers
                 </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2"></script>
  <!-- place project specific Javascript in this file -->
  <script src="{% static 'js/project.js' %}"></script>
  <script>
    {% include 'vue_dashboard.js' %}
</script>

</body>
```

the vue_dashboard.js file is the following

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue_app',
    delimiters: ["{(", ")}"],
    data: function () {
        return {
            selected: 'group',
        }
    },

    methods: {
        change_selected: function (type) {
            this.selected = type;
        },
    }
```

Now, I'm trying to use this vue method inside my `<a>` tag for example like this:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="change_selected(type='customers')">
                      customers
</a>
```

then inside some other div obtain the value of the `selected` variable in the data section:

```
<div>
{{selected}}
</div>
```

I've also tried:

```
{% verbatim %}
{{ selected }}
{% endverbatim %}
```

and few other things, I know I'm using it wrong, but what's the right way to do so? I'm not even sure if my template can communicate with the vue file like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem was like @ashwin said with the brackets, the other one was that the Vue app closing brackets were missing, also `onclick` doesn't work, I replaced it with `@click`, then everything was okay

Answer (score 1):

Change

```html
<a href="#" onclick="change_selected('customers')"> <!-- removed type= -->
  customers
</a>
```

this should work with `verbatim` but you can also change delimiters in vue.js like following

```js
delimiters: ["{(", ")}"],
```

which you did but didn't change `{{` to `{(` so please change like this:

```html
<div>
{( selected )} // <= change here
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I've did the changes you mentioned, but it didn't work, it printed `{(selected)}`, any further ideas?

Comment: it is printing `{(selected)}` means vue is not working on; check if console has any error.'